# C# WebBrowser HtmlElement.InnerText doesn't work

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to fill a form field in a WebBrowser control using HtmlElement.InnerText. The field is pre-filled with some greyed out placeholder text "Search your purchases", but when I fill the field with my own text it's also greyed out and has no effect when I click the submit button.

If I type the text into the field manually instead it's black and works allright when I click submit.

How do I get this to work? Here's the form html:

```
<form role="form" action="/mod/bcs/account/" method="get" class="margin-top-20">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="searchPurchases" type="text" placeholder="Search your purchases" value="" id="search-bcs">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My own code:

```
HtmlElement searchBox = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("search-bcs");
            searchBox.InnerText = "text";
```

Comment: Where is the code where you set the `InnerText`?

Comment: It's not the `InnerText` you need to set. It's the `Value` attribute.

Comment: Hm, OK. How do I do that?

Comment: Using [`HtmlElement.SetAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx): `searchBox.SetAttribute("value", "text");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by my comments, the value contained by an `<input>` element is held in the `value` attribute, and not in a child text node.

If you want to change the value through code, you need to use [HtmlElement.SetAttribute()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
searchBox.SetAttribute("value", "text");
```